# RStudio: Closing parenthesis overwritten

Tags: r, rstudio, parentheses

I am doing a stastitics course in R, and while it is pretty great in many aspects, it is annoying as hell in one. That is, if I have nested parentheses, and I want to wrap a function around something, the closing parenthesis gets overwritten, unless I am not just outside of it.

```
bla(xxx) # start here
blu(bla(xxx*) # Type blu, move with Ctrl+> to the star and type ')'
blu(bla(xxx)) # What I expect
blu(bla(xxx)  # What I get
```

Is there a way to turn this off? I could not find an option in the settings, only some regex hacking ideas on other pages.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within RStudio, go to `Tools -> Global Options -> Code` Within this tab, **uncheck** `Insert matching parens/quotes`. This turns this behaviour off but unfortunately also the quoting which is useful.

[image: Code screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, it's a small price to pay :)

Comment: That annoyed me for years. Never really looked that up. Why is this the default???

Comment: I kind of got used to it and it is always depressing using a normal text editor which is not that 'intelligent' :-)